# Copy Constructor Test not Working (Java)

Tags: java, object, copy

I'm working on CS homework and have run into a problem. The end of the homework asks about using a copy constructor. The goal is to "make one Payroll object, instantiate it, make a second one, then print them both.  Then, change values in the second Payroll object, and show that the changed values only appear in one and not both (that is, print out the original and the copy with slightly changed values)." I tried changing the values in the second Payroll object, but it also changes it in the first. I've listed my code below:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Payroll {
private int[] employeeId;
private int[] hours;
private double[] payRate;

public Payroll(){
    this.employeeId = new int[0];
    this.hours = new int[0];
    this.payRate = new double[0];
}

public Payroll(Payroll obj){
    this.employeeId = obj.employeeId;
    this.hours = obj.hours;
    this.payRate = obj.payRate;
}

public Payroll(int i){
    this.employeeId = new int[i];
    this.hours = new int[i];
    this.payRate = new double[i];

}

public int getEmployeeIdAt(int index){
    return employeeId[index];   
}

public int getHoursAt(int index){
    return hours[index];
}

public double getPayRateAt(int index){
    return payRate[index];
}

public double getGrossPay(int index){
    double grossPay = hours[index] * payRate[index];
    grossPay = Math.round(grossPay * 100);
    return grossPay/100;
}

public void setEmployeeIdAt(int index, int id){
    this.employeeId[index] = id;
}

public void setHoursAt(int index, int hrs){
    this.hours[index] = hrs;
}

public void setPayRateAt(int index, double pr){
    this.payRate[index] = pr;
}

public void setHoursAt(int i){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randHours = rand.nextInt((50 - 15) + 1) + 15;
    this.hours[i] = randHours;
}
}

import java.util.Scanner;


public class PayrollDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Payroll pr = new Payroll(5);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int empID = 1001;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pr.setEmployeeIdAt(i, empID);
        empID++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the hourly pay rate for employee number "        + pr.getEmployeeIdAt(i) + ": ");
        double payRate = scan.nextDouble();
        if(payRate < 7.50){
            do{
                System.out.println("ERROR: Enter 7.50 or greater for pay rate: ");
                payRate = scan.nextDouble();
            } while(payRate < 7.50);
        }
        pr.setPayRateAt(i, payRate);
        pr.setHoursAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println("PAYROLL DATA");
    System.out.println("======================");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("Employee ID: " + pr.getEmployeeIdAt(i) + "       Hours: " + pr.getHoursAt(i) + "    Rate: " + pr.getPayRateAt(i) + 
                "    Gross Pay: $" + pr.getGrossPay(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to run the Copy Constructor Test? Enter 'y' (lowercase) if yes, enter any other letter if no: ");
    char copyTestVerify = scan.next().charAt(0);
    if(copyTestVerify == 'y'){
        CopyConstructorTest ct = new CopyConstructorTest();
        ct.CopyTest();
    }

    scan.close();
}

}
```

The following is my CopyConstructorTest class, the one that tests whether or not the copy constructor will change the original object's values:

```
public class CopyConstructorTest {
    public void CopyTest(){
        Payroll pay = new Payroll(5);
        pay.setEmployeeIdAt(0, 1001);

        Payroll payCopy = new Payroll(pay);
        System.out.println("Original: " + pay.getEmployeeIdAt(0));
        System.out.println("Copy: " + payCopy.getEmployeeIdAt(0));
        payCopy.setEmployeeIdAt(0, 5000);
        System.out.println("Original after changes: " +     pay.getEmployeeIdAt(0));
        System.out.println("Copy after changes: " + payCopy.getEmployeeIdAt(0));

    }
}
```

I'm not positive on what I'm doing wrong. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to copy the data in the arrays, not just the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just copying the references to the arrays, not the actual data. Therefore whenever you change the data in one of your objects, the changes are seen in both, since they point to the same array.
The easiest way to copy the data is probably using [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
public Payroll(Payroll obj) {
    this.employeeId = new int[obj.employeeId.length];
    System.arraycopy(obj.employeeId, 0, this.employeeId, 0, obj.employeeId.length);
    ...
```